# How can wait my Telegram Bot for a incoming message?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

How can I let interact my Telegram Bot with Users? E.g.:

> User: /buy
>
> Bot: What do you want to buy?
>
> User: Icecream
>
> Bot: You have successfully bought Icecream!

So how can I do this?

```
switch($message) {
[...]
case "/buy":
    sendMessage($chatID, "What do you want to buy?");
    //Here I need your help :D
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a webhook to receive updates, your php script runs again on every update you are receiving.
In this case, you will need to save a certain "status" of the user which you are checking everytime your bot receives a message to indicate what you have to do next.
An example would be:

```
switch($message) {
case "/buy":
    sendMessage($chatID, "What do you want to buy? Icecream, Water or Sprite?");
    $storage[$chatID]['status'] = 'awaitingProductChoice';
    saveStorage();
    break;
}
```

You need to save $storage[$userId] somehow (`saveStorage();`). Ideally would be to use a database, if you haven't got one, use `file_put_contents('storage.json', json_encode($storage));` or something similar to serialize it. SESSIONS won't work, since Telegram Servers do not send cookies.

Then place some similar code before your switch statement:

```
$storage = readStorage(); // load from DB or file_get_contents from file
if ($storage[$chatID]['status'] === 'awaitingProductChoice') {
    // return " You have successfully bought Icecream!"
    $storage[$chatID]['product choice'] = $message['text'];
} else if ($storage[$chatID]['status'] === 'other stuff') {
    // other step
}
else switch($message) [...]
```

Comment: Your answer is interesting, but can you please edit your answer to my edited Question? I mean: How can I e.g. save the incoming answer to a string or to an array?

Comment: @Deeonix That's simple, just save the text the user sent you. I edited my answer, maybe it helps you.

Comment: And how exactly should readStorage() and saveStorage() looks like?

Comment: That depends on the way you want to read/ store your user data.
E.g. if you want to use a storage.json file then it would be
`function readStoreage { return json_decode(file_get_contents('storage.json'), true);}`

Comment: But what is when another user send /buy to the bot?

Comment: That's why we are using the $chatID as an idex. Every user has its own ['status']

Comment: I don't get it... Can you send please a Full example code? 

Comment: I have this functions and the code from above, but it doesn't work!
`function saveStorage() {
 file_put_contents('storage.json', json_encode($storage));
}
function readStorage() {
 return json_decode(file_get_contents('storage.json'), true);
}`

Comment: Ok, you got a serious problem on a very low level. I just don't have all the time to help you out in this problem. If I find enough time later, I might send you a working demo script. Could you please upload your script to pastebin or whatever and send me the link, so I can see what you got so far?

Comment: Okay, this problem extends the capacity of StackOverflow. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are utilizing a webhook to receive updates, it is important to note that your php script will execute each time an update is received. Consequently, it becomes necessary to store a specific "status" of the user, which will be checked each time your bot receives a message. This "status" will serve as an indicator of the subsequent action that needs to be taken. Allow me to provide an example for better understanding.

Comment: Hello. where's the example?